# Error in view account reputation

Tags: support

When I access my StackOverflow account I see my rep on Super User is 1 rep.

[Links to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1138318/huynh-vinh-phat)
[image: SO image]

But when I access Super User I see I had 101 rep.

[Links to SU](https://superuser.com/users/144819/huynh-vinh-phat)
[image: SuperUSer image]

I don't know why this happens. Can anyone explain why I get these different values?

Comment: Probably caching. Did you recently associate your accounts on [SO] and [SU], giving you the account-association bonus?

Comment: When I associate SO and meta SO, I got 100 rep on SO. But there are no rep bonus when I associate SO and SU.

Comment: Since your reputation score on SU is now 101, it looks like you _did_ get it. When did you associate the accounts?

Comment: @S.L.Barth at July 9th it's visible in the [reputation tab](http://superuser.com/users/144819/huynh-vinh-phat?tab=reputation)

Comment: Sr, I don't remember exactly. But i can remember that i associate with SU after I associated with SO Meta about 2 hour.

Comment: Sometimes some actual activity on the account which is not correctly updated seems to trigger an update. Perhaps you can try that.

Comment: Thanks you. I changed my profile but i have no luck.

Comment: I meant anything that can give you some rep. A suggested edit perhaps.

Comment: Oh! Sr for that. Did you means I get rep from SU like ShaWizDowArd's answer?

Comment: Thanks all for yours support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "per site" accounts list appears to be cached, as you can see [your network profile accounts list](https://stackexchange.com/users/1158270/huynh-vinh-phat?tab=accounts) show the correct reputation.

More than once I have seen Nick saying something about "reputation events" that triggers cache refresh, so I believe that once you will gain some reputation on Super User it will all be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will take a try.

Comment: Some rep events do indeed seem to have solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks Sha Wiz Dow Ard. After i gain some reputation on SU, every things are now fixed.